# How to remove touch offset on webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I'm experimenting with some touch integration with my web app and i'm noticing that with the code posted below the block that moves on touch has a costant offset and I can temporarly remove it by going in f11 mode. How do i remove it such that the block is always under the finger?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" 
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<head>
<title>A title</title>
</head>
<style>
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="bup" style="position:absolute; background-color:blue;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>

<script>
var touch = [];

document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    touch = event.touches;
    document.getElementById('bup').style.top= (touch[0].screenY-50) + 'px';
    document.getElementById('bup').style.left= (touch[0].screenX-50) + 'px';
}, false); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(the -50 is there just to center the block on my finger considering that the block it self is 100x100px)

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i solved it my self.
the issue was the `touch[0].screenX`. I shoud have used `touch[0].clientX`, same for the Y.

Hope this helps someone, see ya